# dIjango-websocket-redis Module Error on Installation

Tags: python, django, redis, pip

When I run django server, It says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ws4redis'".

When I try to install ws4redis using the PIP command, I says syntax error.

```
pip install django-websocket-redis
```

Here is the tracebacks of the errors:

```
Collecting django-websocket-redis
Using cached django-websocket-redis-0.5.1.tar.gz
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 412, in run_egg_info
    self.setup_py, self.name,
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/Users/ranjan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
  File "/Users/ranjan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "/Users/ranjan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 103
    except ValueError, e:
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Something is very strange in your Python 3 installation. It should not be importing `setuptools` from `/Users/ranjan/.local/lib/python2.7`.

Comment: If you are using `Python 3.x`, then try `pip3 install django-websocket-redis`